# SQL Profiler Template File Format

Tags: sql-server, profiler

Does anyone have information on the file format used to hold SQL Profiler Templates (NOT Profiler trace files)? Or a way to create or parse these via C#?

Thanks very much.

Comment: There's a bit of a clunky workaround [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/321971/trace-definition-files-tdf-should-be-available-in-xml) if you don't find anything better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but you can programmatically create and run traces w/ the `sp_trace%` family of stored procedures, if that helps at all.

The process goes something like `sp_trace_create` -> `sp_trace_setevent`, `sp_trace_setfilter` -> `sp_trace_setstatus`

You might also investigate extended events. The learning curve is a little steep, but they allow for more fine-grained data collection than a SQL trace, for some event types at least.