# How to programatically update SQL Server Profiler template

Tags: c#, io, sql-server-profiler

I work with a variety of databases for work on any given day. I have built a C# tool that changes which database my system is connecting to for testing.

When I change the connection details for my database, I would like to also update this value in my SQL Server Profiler template (not trace file - the actual template).

I found this question from 12 years ago with no answer: [SQL Profiler Template File Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3636467/sql-profiler-template-file-format)

I'm curious if there might be any new insight in the past decade that could be useful here?

The file is a `*.tdf` file, and the contents are not readable in plain text.

However, my database name as defined in the template properties is in plain text.

I have looked at reading the file contents as strings, but it considers those NULL values string terminators which means I haven't been able to access the database value between them.

I have also played with `ReadAllBytes` and then trying to extract the bytes that way - but haven't been successful - though this seems the most probable approach so far.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to modify the `*.tdf` file programmatically so I can simply set my database name directly into the file?

It's worth noting, that if I open the file in notepad++, modify the database name there, and save, the Profiler GUI will reflect the changes correctly - so I believe doing it programmatically should work provided I can come up with a way how.

[image]

Comment: I found a method using Powershell.  See : https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/big-data-and-business-intelligence/9781785283321/7/ch07lvl1sec127/running-and-saving-a-profiler-trace-event

Comment: Side note: you should probably switch to using Extended Events (XEvents) as they are more efficient and more flexible, and you can also change them using T-SQL

Comment: Clearly I'm in a bubble - I didn't know SQL Profiler was deprecated. I'll start reading up on Extended events, might make my question moot. Thanks!